# how can i creating next and prev page

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to make 2 page to store 3 video in 1 page by hiding the div. i set .video-section-wrapper-1 display to flex and .video-section-wrapper-2 display: none; and using javascript to switch the 2 container display .video-section-wrapper-1 to none and video-section-wrapper - 2 to flex i can't point out where i go wrong in the javascript.

Here's my code

```
var leftbtn = document.querySelector(".leftslide").addEventListener("click", moveslide(0));
var rightbtn = document.querySelector(".rightslide").addEventListener("click", moveslide(1));

var slidelist = [];

slidelist[0] = document.getElementsByClassName("video-section-wrapper-1");
slidelist[1] = document.getElementsByClassName("video-section-wrapper-2");
function moveslide(a){
   if(a == 1){
    slidelist[0].style.display = "none";
    slidelist[1].style.display = "flex";
   } else if(a == 0){
    slidelist[0].style.display = "flex";
    slidelist[1].style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    
}

/* Nav-Bar */
.nav-bar-wrapper {
    display: flex;  
    padding: 5px;  
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: orange 3px solid;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 5);
}



.button-wrapper {
    margin: 5px;
}

.button-wrapper > button{
    display: flex;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.button-wrapper > button > .icon-wrapper , .button-text{
    color: orange;
    padding: 5px;
}

.button-wrapper:hover > button > .icon-wrapper > i ,.button-wrapper:hover > button > .button-text{
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}


.button-wrapper:hover , button:hover , .icon-wrapper:hover , .button-text:hover {
    color: whitesmoke;
    background-color: black;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.button-wrapper > button > .button-text{
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;

}

.nav-bar-background-wrapper {
    background-image: url(img/guitarback.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    
    
}


/*Video Section*/

.video-section-wrapper-2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-top: orange 5px solid;
    border-bottom: orange 5px solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

.video-section-wrapper-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-top: orange 5px solid;
    border-bottom: orange 5px solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

.video-section-box {
    height: 90%;
    width: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),-1px -1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: 0.5s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-section-wrapper-1 > .video-section-box {
    border: solid black 5px;
}

.video-section-wrapper-2 > .video-section-box {
    border: solid orange 5px;
}

.video-section-box:hover {
    height: 93%;
    width: 30%;
}

.video-section-box > .video-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 154px;
    outline: none;
    border: 0px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    position: relative;
}

.video-section-box > .video-container > iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0px;
}

.video-section-box > .subtitle-wrapper {
    border-top: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) solid 5px;
    height: 92px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.video-section-box > .subtitle-wrapper > .subtitle-header {
    padding-left: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.video-section-box > .subtitle-wrapper > .subtitle-header > h {
    background-color: black;
    color: wheat;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-size: 300px 300px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.video-section-box > .subtitle-wrapper > .subtitle-content {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: 0px;
    height: 84px;
    color: wheat;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.capo-wrap {
    font-size: 17px;
    position: absolute;
    color: wheat;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 78px;
}

.capo-wrap > p{
    margin: 0px;
}

.video-section-box > .subtitle-wrapper > .subtitle-content > .p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 30px;
}

/*Slide BTN*/
.btnbtn{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.slidebtn {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    bottom: 210px;
}

.leftslide,
.rightslide {
    background-color: rgba(207, 207, 207, 0.699);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;

}

.leftslide > i,
.rightslide > i {
    font-weight: bolder;
} 

.leftslide {
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<head>
        <title>Lopzx TABS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="img/icon/guitar.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <script href="main-javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--Navbar-->
        <div class="nav-bar-wrapper">

            <div class="button-wrapper">
                <button>
                    <div class="icon-wrapper"><i class="material-icons">home</i></div>
                    <div class="button-text">HOME</div>                   
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="button-wrapper">
                <button>
                    <div class="icon-wrapper"><i class="material-icons">description</i></div>
                    <div class="button-text">TAB</div>                   
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-bar-background-wrapper"></div>

        <!--Body-->
        <div class="video-section-wrapper-1">
            <div class="video-section-box">
                <div class="video-container">
                    <iframe class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LKEKzbLG50M" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>

                <div class="subtitle-wrapper">
                    <div class="subtitle-header">
                        <h>TUNING</h>                    
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="capo-wrap"><p>Capo Fret :</p></div>

                    <div class="subtitle-content">
                        <div class="p">E A D G B E</div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="video-section-box">
                <div class="video-container">
                    <iframe class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LKEKzbLG50M" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>

                <div class="subtitle-wrapper">
                    <div class="subtitle-header">
                        <h>TUNING</h>                    
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="capo-wrap"><p>Capo Fret :</p></div>

                    <div class="subtitle-content">
                        <div class="p">E A D G B E</div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="video-section-box">
                <div class="video-container">
                    <iframe class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LKEKzbLG50M" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>

                <div class="subtitle-wrapper">
                    <div class="subtitle-header">
                        <h>TUNING</h>                    
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="capo-wrap"><p>Capo Fret :</p></div>

                    <div class="subtitle-content">
                        <div class="p">E A D G B E</div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>

                
            </div>

            
        </div>

        <div class="video-section-wrapper-2">
            <div class="video-section-box">
                <div class="video-container">
                    <iframe class="video"></iframe>
                </div>

                <div class="subtitle-wrapper">
                    <div class="subtitle-header">
                        <h>TUNING</h>                    
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="capo-wrap"><p>Capo Fret :</p></div>

                    <div class="subtitle-content">
                        <div class="p">E A D G B E</div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="video-section-box">
                <div class="video-container">
                    <iframe class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LKEKzbLG50M" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>

                <div class="subtitle-wrapper">
                    <div class="subtitle-header">
                        <h>TUNING</h>                    
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="capo-wrap"><p>Capo Fret :</p></div>

                    <div class="subtitle-content">
                        <div class="p">E A D G B E</div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="video-section-box">
                <div class="video-container">
                    <iframe class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LKEKzbLG50M" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>

                <div class="subtitle-wrapper">
                    <div class="subtitle-header">
                        <h>TUNING</h>                    
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="capo-wrap"><p>Capo Fret :</p></div>

                    <div class="subtitle-content">
                        <div class="p">E A D G B E</div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>

                
            </div>

            
        </div>

        <div class="btnbtn">
            <div class="slidebtn">
                <button class="leftslide">
                    <i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>
                </button>
                <button class="rightslide">
                    <i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>
    
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
 function moveslide(a) {
        
        if (a == 0) {
            $('.video-section-wrapper-2').css('display','flex');
            $('.video-section-wrapper-1').css('display', 'none');
        } else if (a == 1) {
            $('.video-section-wrapper-1').css('display', 'flex');
            $('.video-section-wrapper-2').css('display', 'none');
        }
    }
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    
}

/* Nav-Bar */
.nav-bar-wrapper {
    display: flex;  
    padding: 5px;  
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: orange 3px solid;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 5);
}



.button-wrapper {
    margin: 5px;
}

.button-wrapper > button{
    display: flex;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.button-wrapper > button > .icon-wrapper , .button-text{
    color: orange;
    padding: 5px;
}

.button-wrapper:hover > button > .icon-wrapper > i ,.button-wrapper:hover > button > .button-text{
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}


.button-wrapper:hover , button:hover , .icon-wrapper:hover , .button-text:hover {
    color: whitesmoke;
    background-color: black;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.button-wrapper > button > .button-text{
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;

}

.nav-bar-background-wrapper {
    background-image: url(img/guitarback.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    
    
}


/*Video Section*/

.video-section-wrapper-2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-top: orange 5px solid;
    border-bottom: orange 5px solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

.video-section-wrapper-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-top: orange 5px solid;
    border-bottom: orange 5px solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

.video-section-box {
    height: 90%;
    width: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),-1px -1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: 0.5s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-section-wrapper-1 > .video-section-box {
    border: solid black 5px;
}

.video-section-wrapper-2 > .video-section-box {
    border: solid orange 5px;
}

.video-section-box:hover {
    height: 93%;
    width: 30%;
}

.video-section-box > .video-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 154px;
    outline: none;
    border: 0px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    position: relative;
}

.video-section-box > .video-container > iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0px;
}

.video-section-box > .subtitle-wrapper {
    border-top: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) solid 5px;
    height: 92px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.video-section-box > .subtitle-wrapper > .subtitle-header {
    padding-left: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.video-section-box > .subtitle-wrapper > .subtitle-header > h {
    background-color: black;
    color: wheat;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-size: 300px 300px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.video-section-box > .subtitle-wrapper > .subtitle-content {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: 0px;
    height: 84px;
    color: wheat;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.capo-wrap {
    font-size: 17px;
    position: absolute;
    color: wheat;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 78px;
}

.capo-wrap > p{
    margin: 0px;
}

.video-section-box > .subtitle-wrapper > .subtitle-content > .p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 30px;
}

/*Slide BTN*/
.btnbtn{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.slidebtn {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    bottom: 210px;
}

.leftslide,
.rightslide {
    background-color: rgba(207, 207, 207, 0.699);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;

}

.leftslide > i,
.rightslide > i {
    font-weight: bolder;
} 

.leftslide {
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<head>
        <title>Lopzx TABS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="img/icon/guitar.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <script href="main-javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
       
<!--Navbar-->
<div class="nav-bar-wrapper">

    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button>
            <div class="icon-wrapper"><i class="material-icons">home</i></div>
            <div class="button-text">HOME</div>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button>
            <div class="icon-wrapper"><i class="material-icons">description</i></div>
            <div class="button-text">TAB</div>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="nav-bar-background-wrapper"></div>

<!--Body-->
<div class="video-section-wrapper-1">
    <div class="video-section-box">
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe class="video" src="" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="subtitle-wrapper">
            <div class="subtitle-header">
                <h>TUNING</h>
            </div>

            <div class="capo-wrap"><p>Capo Fret :</p></div>

            <div class="subtitle-content">
                <div class="p">E A D G B E</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="video-section-box">
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe class="video" src="" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="subtitle-wrapper">
            <div class="subtitle-header">
                <h>TUNING</h>
            </div>

            <div class="capo-wrap"><p>Capo Fret :</p></div>

            <div class="subtitle-content">
                <div class="p">E A D G B E</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="video-section-box">
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe class="video" src="" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="subtitle-wrapper">
            <div class="subtitle-header">
                <h>TUNING</h>
            </div>

            <div class="capo-wrap"><p>Capo Fret :</p></div>

            <div class="subtitle-content">
                <div class="p">E A D G B E</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>




<div class="video-section-wrapper-2">
    <div class="video-section-box">
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe class="video"></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="subtitle-wrapper">
            <div class="subtitle-header">
                <h>TUNING</h>
            </div>

            <div class="capo-wrap"><p>Capo Fret :</p></div>

            <div class="subtitle-content">
                <div class="p">E A D G B E</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="video-section-box">
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe class="video" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="subtitle-wrapper">
            <div class="subtitle-header">
                <h>TUNING</h>
            </div>

            <div class="capo-wrap"><p>Capo Fret :</p></div>

            <div class="subtitle-content">
                <div class="p">E A D G B E</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="video-section-box">
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe class="video" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="subtitle-wrapper">
            <div class="subtitle-header">
                <h>TUNING</h>
            </div>

            <div class="capo-wrap"><p>Capo Fret :</p></div>

            <div class="subtitle-content">
                <div class="p">E A D G B E</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>




<div class="btnbtn">
    <div class="slidebtn">
        <button class="leftslide" onclick="moveslide(0)">
            <i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>
        </button>
        <button class="rightslide" onclick="moveslide(1)">
            <i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>

        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: It's 2021, jquery shouldn't be a solution to any problem not specifically about jquery. Nothing in OPs code is jquery.